# Invalid Syntax error while trying to run any appimage-builder command

Tags: appimage

I need to deploy an application in Linux environment. I tend to use appimage. I read its documantation [here][1] and I installed appimage-builder using installation [page][2] in Ubuntu 16.04. Installation is completed just fine. But, whenever I try to call appimage-builder command such as

```
appimage-builder --version
```

it gives following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/bin/appimage-builder", line 15, in 
> from AppImageBuilder.**main** import **main**   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/AppImageBuilder/**main**.py",
> line 19, in 
> from AppImageBuilder.app_dir.builder import Builder   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/AppImageBuilder/app_dir/builder.py",
> line 15, in 
> from AppImageBuilder.app_dir.runtimes.proot.runtime import PRootRuntime   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/AppImageBuilder/app_dir/runtimes/proot/runtime.py",
> line 13, in 
> from AppImageBuilder.recipe import Recipe   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/AppImageBuilder/recipe.py",
> line 132
> full_value = full_value.replace(f'${{{g}}}', value)
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Python version is 3.5.2 on my system. I searched on the internet for the related error but I couldn't find anything. Is anyone encountered with this problem?
[1]: https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/overview.html
[2]: https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the package [`setup.py` file](https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder/blob/5d6091ed79aa41e6caaad042b341478783f3de75/setup.py#L42) the **required python version is 3.6** or higher. I wonder why you were able to install it in the first place.

That's provably my fault. Please fill an issue at https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder/issues

Answer (score 1):

I update python 3.5.2 to 3.7.9 and it fix it. But I couldn't find python minimum version requirement for Appimage.